# Should we burninate the [spatie] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I propose the tag [spatie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spatie) should be removed. It has about 90 questions.  I believe it does fulfil the 4 criteria for burnination according to [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination)

> **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

This tag is very ambiguous. Spatie is a web development company in Belgium which has a large number of open-source projects mainly for the Laravel PHP framework. Using this tag does not make it clear what the question is about as it could be about any one of those libraries, and there is no thematic connection between each of those libraries other than them being written for Laravel.

> **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

The concept is a collection of open-source projects which are not thematically linked. Knowing something about one of these projects does lead to you knowing something about any of the other projects. As asking about a collection of projects at once would be too broad then I believe this tag is also too broad.

> **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

While the tag *does* add information, it does not add any *meaningful* information. There are no commonalities other than Laravel in any of the libraries the questions are tagged under and as such [Laravel] along with a specific library tag are sufficient to fully describe the question.

> **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

It does not mean the same thing in all common contexts as in all contexts it's used to describe **a specific** library but that specific library is different in almost every question.

---

In addition: I find this tag to not add any additional information to a question which is not already covered by tagging the question with [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) and by the OP saying what library they are using and/or linking to it.

This tag usually refers to one of these tags/libraries:

1. [laravel-permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-permission)
2. [laravel-medialibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-medialibrary)
3. [laravel-backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-backup)

However the spatie github page lists over 300 repositories, many of them for Laravel and some for general PHP libraries.

In many cases the question author would mention or link to the specific package they are using but sometimes this does not happen ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518811/how-can-i-disable-laravel-spatie-signature)). I do believe questions in this tag which refer to libraries that already have a tag can be retagged (which is something that can be done now and I have been doing when I spot such questions). However for the ones with no library tag available the strategy can probably be something like, add library tags if the library is asked about frequently enough (e.g. there's more than a handful of questions about it) and just remove the tag and add a link to the library page for the rest of the questions.

Comment: Not relevant to the discussion, just a piece of trivia: *spatie* is the [Dutch word for the *space* character](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spatie).

Comment: The general policy is that we don't create company name tags. Straight up burninating won't work here I think, we'll need to add existing or new product tags.

Comment: With only 90 questions with the tag, it isn't a very onerous task for someone who knows enough about the products to clean up manually (or, preferably, a couple of people).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Its also a slang words for a late night shop in Berlin :D

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe I think that would be [spaeti / Späti](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A4tkauf)  ("Ich kauf mir ein Spezi beim Späti?)

Answer (score 4):

The general policy is that we don't create company name tags. Straight up burninating won't work here I think, we'll need to add existing or new product tags.

https://spatie.be/open-source/packages lists over 70 laravel* packages. We could use the package names as tag names, but some of them are ambiguous e.g. laravel-menu also exists [here](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu). Looking at recent questions, it seems some of them would require a "spatie expert" to correctly retag them because it's unclear which package is used.

I've reached out to the company and asked for their input.

Comment: I work at Spatie. Thanks for reaching out. We didn't create the tag. Currently we have no time to retag questions. Feel free to do whatever you think is best with the existing tags. Should you have specific questions for me, feel free to contact me again.

Comment: I don't think we need to create a tag for each package that they list. A couple of tags for frequently used/asked about packages should be enough. I've only seen 4-5 such cases with laravel-permissions being a popular example

Comment: @apokryfos I'll try putting up some suggestions tonight and mark it as community wiki. Ideally we'd have all 121 questions listed here.